# What does @ symbol mean in a function in yacc

Tags: postgresql, yacc

I'm reading the yacc file from postgres's github repo and find [this line](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/4cb65e10722164fd12c6b8d010a39ce0f92e71f9/src/pl/plpgsql/src/pl_gram.y#L415) with a `@2`. I'm not sure how to understand what this symbol mean.

```
pl_block        : decl_sect K_BEGIN proc_sect exception_sect K_END opt_label
                    {
                        PLpgSQL_stmt_block *new;

                        new = palloc0(sizeof(PLpgSQL_stmt_block));

                        new->cmd_type   = PLPGSQL_STMT_BLOCK;
                        new->lineno     = plpgsql_location_to_lineno(@2);
                        new->stmtid     = ++plpgsql_curr_compile->nstatements;
                        new->label      = $1.label;
                        new->n_initvars = $1.n_initvars;
                        new->initvarnos = $1.initvarnos;
                        new->body       = $3;
                        new->exceptions = $4;

                        check_labels($1.label, $6, @6);
                        plpgsql_ns_pop();

                        $$ = (PLpgSQL_stmt *) new;
                    }
                ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [location structure](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Locations) corresponding to the second symbol in the production (in this case, the `K_BEGIN` keyword).